# Generating the same advanced item in multiple namespaces

Tags: terraform

I've got the following variable in a module:

```
variable "container_registries" {
  type = list(object({
    name       = string
    addl_keys  = list(string)
    namespaces = set(string)
    hostnames  = list(string)
    username   = string
    password   = string
  }))
  default = []
}
```

I'm feeding the module variable as such:

```
container_registries = [
  {
    name : "server.example.com"
    addl_keys : ["config.json"]
    namespaces : ["flux-system", "tekton"]
    hostnames : ["cr-lts.server.example.com", "cr-test.server.example.com"]
    username : "foo"
    password : "bar"
  }
]
```

Now I need to create multiple [Kubernetes Secrets](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/secret), each in different namespaces - but with the same content. I need the Secrets in the `flux-system` and `tekton` namespace. I need the secret to look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson
metadata:
  name: server.example.com
data:
  .dockerconfigjson: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJjci1sdHMuc2VydmVyLmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIjp7ImF1dGgiOiJabTl2T21KaGNnbz0ifSwiY3ItdGVzdC5zZXJ2ZXIuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iOnsiYXV0aCI6IlptOXZPbUpoY2dvPSJ9fX0K
  config.json: eyJhdXRocyI6eyJjci1sdHMuc2VydmVyLmV4YW1wbGUuY29tIjp7ImF1dGgiOiJabTl2T21KaGNnbz0ifSwiY3ItdGVzdC5zZXJ2ZXIuZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iOnsiYXV0aCI6IlptOXZPbUpoY2dvPSJ9fX0K
```

Note that the Secret has two different keys, each with the same value. The `.dockerconfigjson` key is mandatory when the Secret type is set to `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson`, so it should always be included. The value is a base64 encoded JSON and the JSON looks as such:

```
{
  "auths": {
    "cr-lts.server.example.com": {
      "auth": "Zm9vOmJhcgo="
    },
    "cr-test.server.example.com": {
        "auth": "Zm9vOmJhcgo="
      }
  }
}
```

The value of `auth` is `foo:bar` (the username and password) in base64.

I've been trying and trying, but I am not getting any closer. All my attempts have felt like garbage  How in the world can I achieve this with Terraform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to solve the problem, using @Kreetchy's answer as a base:

```js
locals {
  container_registries = toset(flatten([
    for cr in var.container_registries : [
      for ns in cr.namespaces : format("%s/%s", ns, cr.name)
    ]
  ]))

  container_registry_data = {
    for cr in var.container_registries : cr.name => {
      for key in toset(concat([".dockerconfigjson"], cr.addl_keys)) : key => jsonencode({
        auths = {
          for hostname in cr.hostnames : hostname => {
            auth = base64encode("${cr.username}:${cr.password}")
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "container_registry" {
  for_each = local.container_registries
  metadata {
    namespace = split("/", each.value)[0]
    name      = split("/", each.value)[1]
  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
  data = local.container_registry_data[split("/", each.value)[1]]
}
```

Note the extra `local.container_registries` which is used for the loop in the `resource`. This `local` stores the `namespace/name` of the secret in the list. The drawback is that two secrets by the same name and different content can not be created in two namespaces. It's something I can live with :-)

I also renamed `var.keys` to `var.addl_keys`, because a key by the name of `.dockerconfigjson` always must exist in a `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` kind of Secret.

@Kreetchy: Please feel free to copy the code above and put it into your answer and I'll mark it as accepted. Once done, I will edit my question to adapt the requirement to fit the answer :-)

Comment: No you can put yours as the accepted one as you managed to solve it via the hints, I don't mind at all.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve it this way in Terraform

```
locals {
  secret_data = {
    for registry in var.container_registries : {
      for key in registry.keys : key => base64encode(jsonencode({
        auths = {
          for hostname in registry.hostnames : hostname => {
            auth = base64encode("${registry.username}:${registry.password}")
          }
        }
      }))
    }
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_secret" "example" {
  for_each = flatten([for registry in var.container_registries : registry.namespaces])
  metadata {
    name      = lookup(var.container_registries[each.key].name, each.value)
    namespace = each.value
  }
  type = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
  data = {
    for key, value in local.secret_data : key => value
  }
}
```

This will handle a list of varying amount of entries in the container_registries variable, and create a separate kubernetes_secret resource for each namespace. The contents of the secrets will still be the encoded JSON, but this time generated dynamically based on the number of keys and hostnames specified in each entry in the container_registries variable.

This handles any number of keys, namespaces and hosts dynamically and will create separate `kuberneteds_secret` resource for each namespace. Content of secret is still encoded JSON, but generated dynamically based on number of keys and hostnames specified in `container_registries`

Comment: The thing is that the amount of keys, namespaces or hosts isn't static. How to solve that?

Comment: @brovoca I have updated the answer with dynamic generation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, impressive! One thing missing though... var.container_registries is currently only allowed to contain 1 item as you reference it using var.container_registries[0]. Can this be changed to support a list of varying amount of entries?

Comment: @brovoca For sure, I have updated the code and it now handle a list of varying amount of entries in the `container_registries` variable. If this is what you were looking for, please mark the answer by pressing the green tick on the left side.

Comment: Hmm, something seems wonky. I'm getting "Invalid 'for' expression: Key expression is required when building an object.". I'm trying to make it work myself, but I'm not there yet :-)

Comment: Try replace `data = local.secret_data[each.value]` to `data = {
    for key, value in local.secret_data : key => value
  }` and let me know

Comment: No, doesn't help. The error is with `for_each = { for registry in var.container_registries : registry.namespaces }`. Should've mentioned that. Sorry

Comment: Hmm it's probably because the `for_each` expects a map/set, but the expression is returning a list of lists. Try to use `flatten` to make it into a single list and see how it goes

Comment: Hey Kreetchy, please check my answer!